# SQL Server: Can't alter nvarchar column length because of "dependent on column" error

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to shorten the length of a `nvarchar` column. None of the existing data in the `nvarchar` exceeds the new length.

```
ALTER TABLE [MyObject]  
    ALTER COLUMN [Alias] NVARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
```

Error:

> The object 'MyObject_OppID_70e6d249_uniq' is dependent on column 'Alias'

I don't understand how another column is dependent on a non-foreign-key `nvarchar` column.

Comment: What about indexes? Or stored procedures or triggers? It doesn't have to be *another column*. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=The+object+is+dependent+on+column

Comment: Check about mentioned object - select * from sys.objects where name = 'MyObject_OppID_70e6d249_uniq'

Comment: It's not another column, it's a **unique constraint** that's set on this column you're trying to alter. You need to drop that constraint first, alter your column, and then re-create that constraint again

Answer (score 1):

You should first drop the constraint like

```
ALTER TABLE  [MyObject] DROP CONSTRAINT MyObject_OppID_70e6d249_uniq;
```

Similarly you might required to drop other dependent constraints on the column.

After that you should be able to alter the column.

```
ALTER TABLE [MyObject] ALTER COLUMN [Alias] nvarchar(64) NOT NULL
```

Once done, you can re-create the required constraints by altering the table.